# Resources on the Bogo-Indian opening

Tags: opening, bogo-indian-defense

I'm looking for good resources to learning the Bogo-Indian opening:

```
 [FEN ""]
 1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nf3 Bb4+.
```

For background purposes, I play at around the 1750 elo level. I like closed positions (I play the Caro-Kann & Slav defence as Black, & always open with 1. d4 as White). Lastly, I'm motivated to learn the Bogo-Indian because I'd like to avoid the Nimzo-Indian.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to confirm - it seems from your question that you want to play the Bogo from white's perspective. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'd like to play the White side of this opening.

Comment: You probably want to take a look at a repertoire book for white with d4-c4-Nf3 - unfortunately I can't recommend any (I'm an Nc3 player myself - is the Nimzo really so bad? :)) sco-ish's suggestion of Avrukh seems like a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a moderate chapter on it in [Boris Avrukh's 1.d4 Volume 2](http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/products/1/53/grandmaster_repertoire_2_-_1d4_volume_2_-_by_boris_avrukh/), you can download a pdf excerpt from the website to see.

And the [Sielecki book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1781941092) is at the time of writing (Nov 24 2014) not out yet (Jan 31 2015).

Other than that there aren't many decent works on this, and if so, most of them are outdated, scanning through databases and viewing GM games (preferably with annotations) can help a lot though.

There are also various videos on youtube, just search up the opening name

A [Chessbase DVD by IM Andrew Martin](http://shop.chessbase.com/en/products/martin_the_abc_of_bogo_indian) covers it solely

Alternatively you can check the C[hess Publishing Forum](http://www.chesspub.com/cgi-bin/chess/YaBB.pl?board=bogo)

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite chess you-tuber's - IM Christof Sielecki has written a book on it: Opening Repertoire: Nimzo and Bogo Indian [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1781941092/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1781941092)

It would be worth to take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

The Complete Bogo-Indian Defense by International Master Maxim Chetverik is a pretty good resource. Here is the link.

https://www.newinchess.com/the-complete-bogo-indian-defense